# Pandas dataframe math.isnan faster than boolean check

Tags: python, pandas, null, boolean, nan

I was wondering if you have a df and filter for example like the following

```
df = df[math.isnan(df.columnA)]
```

is it faster than for same number of true/false evaluations as

```
df = df[df.columnB == True] #(or df = df[df.columnB])
```

I thought null checks are faster than true/false checks but I'm not sure in this case.

I'm not sure if python Not A Number is equally not cpu intensive as null check in for example C#

Comment: Not a duplicate, very specific in depth question, ignore anky_91